# system init and logging failure for diskless pxe boot

Tags: linux, boot, debian, systemd, pxe

I'm going to set up a disk-less cluster and as the first step, I configured a Debian(Jessie) installation as the server and its dhcp, tftp, nfs according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto

For the client, I installed a minimal Debian on a system and copied everything to the server's nfsroot (just like the above howto). Although the client system doesn't have any boot/shutdown problem, the pxe-booted system cannot halt/reboot and returns errors like

> shutdown: timeout opening/writing channel /run/initctl

or

> failed to talk to init deamon

Also it shows some errors repeatedly like this:

> systemd[1]:rsyslog.service start operation timeout. Terminating
>
> failed to start system logging service
>
> unit rsyslog.service entered failed state

and similar one for systemd-journald.service

Some re-installation and reconfiguration of systemd and sysvinit didn't solve the problem.

Any suggestion can be helpful....

Answer (score 0):

Finally I checked around and solved the problem. I don't know what was the reason of the problem, but when I totally replaced the `systemd` with legacy `sysVinit`, the problems solved. It seems that the `systemd` has a problem with remote boot, or it needs some advanced configuration.